# Can't install apps on Watch following iOS update

Tags: ios, apple-watch, bug

Following an update to iOS 14.3, I'm unable to install apps on my Watch, both before and after updating to watchOS 7.2. After clicking the install button in the Watch app, I get the progress indicator for a second or less, and then the process aborts.

How do I restore the ability to install apps on Watch after updating to iOS 14.3?

Comment: Note that I can install using the App Store on the Watch, but that more often than not reveals that the app in question [is already on the Watch, despite not being listed as installed on the Watch app on iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/408951/4395).

Comment: Give both your phone and watch a reboot.  Does that help?

Comment: @ErniePC12 Nope. Tried that a few times in in both orders and no effect.

Comment: Make sure that all of your apps on your iPhone are up to date.

Sometimes, Apple suggest to un-pair and re-pair the watch.  

The nuclear option is to reset both your iPhone and Apple Watch.