# Apps installed on Watch shown as uninstalled on Watch app on iOS

Tags: apple-watch

Numerous apps that are installed on Watch are not indicated as installed under "Installed On Apple Watch" in the Watch am on iOS (even though they're shown correctly as being present under "Arrangement").

How do I ensure that the Watch app on iOS correctly reflects what's installed on my Watch?

Comment: This seems directly related to your question from 20 minutes ago - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408946/cant-install-apps-on-watch-following-ios-update - presumably the cause & cure for one is going to be the cause & cure for the other.

Comment: @Tetsujin Maybe; maybe not. I find that after every update about 50-60 things are broken, and they often have different solutions. (Unless by solution you mean: don't update.)

Comment: tbh, the safest thing to do always is wait & let other people find the bugs first. I used to be a day-0 adopter, but as I feel both macOS & iOS have got less & less stable early releases over the years, I tend to always wait for *at least* the x.x.1 of anything these days.

Comment: @Tetsujin QFT I got carried away after installing Bug Sur (I waited until .1, but even then it clearly has some profound UX/UI problems and bugs) and somehow (a kind of Stockholm syndrome?) while waiting for BS to install I updated my Watch and iPhone, neither of which were (yet again) nearly ready to deploy.